# How to replace a fragment with a fragment of another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Suppose you have 2 activities, 1st activity is main activity with a bottom navigation bar which has 3 fragments as home, search, notification and 2nd activity is profile activity which contains the profile fragment. So now I have a button in main activity which intents me to profile activity so the bottom navigation is not here that I want.

But now in search fragment when I search a user and clicks on his profile, the search fragment should replace with the profile fragment. I did this

```
 profileButton.setOnClickListener {
           startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, ProfileActivity::class.java ))
        }
```

the above code from MainActivity is ok this is what i want but now in UserAdapter class,

```
holder.userItemView.setOnClickListener {
                //...some code for sharedPreference

             //the below code works for intent but i won't it
            // mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext, ProfileActivity::class.java )) 

           //I want this but this is not working
              (mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.profile_fragment_container, ProfileFragment()).commit()
            }
```

Comment: Why did u pass listener from adapter to activity then u can handle logic in that event?

Comment: @ChuongLeVan  The adapter is a user item view in a recycleView in search fragment so when user click on the item it goes to profile fragment and other operation will happen there. And i am following a tutorial on youtube about this but my design is different from him so i am facing the problem.

Comment: Are your logic code to replace fragment not work without error message in logcat?

Comment: @ChuongLeVan  the logic of replace the fragment is not working app crashes and logcat says "cannot find the container for id profile_fragment_container and ProfileFragment() " bute the abouve comment code for intent is working but i want fragment transaction.

Comment: I posted my answer. Pls try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls move your replace fragment logic from adapter to activity which contain replacement container(profile_fragment_container). Because in adapter can not find that replacement container.

You can handle through listener when click view in adapter.

Hope this help.

Comment: no. u just replace logic code in ```holder.userItemView.setOnClickListener``` from adapter to activity(or fragment) contain that adapter.

Comment: I placed the code to search fragment it gives me error about the holder and mContext and when i placed it to mainActivity it do same.

Comment: Do searchFragment or mainActivity contain view profile_fragment_container?

Comment: ok i am explaining again that i want when a user search for users and click on a userItemView in SearchFragment of MainActivity then the user transect to ProfileFragment which is in another activity named ProfileActivity and the profile_fragment_container is id of fragment_profile.xml .

Comment: bro. Remember, when u replace fragment into container(profile_fragment_container). U must do logic in that activity(or fragment) have layout contain that container(profile_fragment_container). else will get error cannot find the container for id profile_fragment_container

Comment: oh sorry this is a link watch 1:40 - 5:25 [link](https://youtu.be/OLLUcDLg-sI)

Comment: yes the code is different, i am not on facebook but in instagram as s.r.t_0011